# resize html project with absolute sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, scale

I have a whole html project (html/css/js) set up with absolute sizes. So if increase the browser window size, the body keeps the same size and does not change. Is there an easy way to increase every single DOM with the aspect ratios when I increase the browser window? So it should kinda behave like when I zoom in on a picture. All the solutions I found were mainly meant for single elements in the html code.

Comment: If you provide your code you'll probably have better luck getting a useful answer.

Comment: css transform:scale could work, but we need a [mcve] including your html and css.

Comment: So -- I didn't downvote this one, and do feel it's a reasonable and worthwhile question -- but you have to bear in mind that SO gets hundreds of questions a day, and a lot of them are terrible "do my work for me" things, so people's delete/downvote triggers are sensitive.  It's worth putting in some effort to make your question clearly stand apart from the chaff.

Comment: Abstract, theoretical questions tend to attract downvotes, and questions without code or other demonstrated effort tend to attract downvotes.  Questions which are clearly looking for workarounds or hacks rather than the "right" way to do the thing tend to attract downvotes. Complaints about downvotes tend to attract *lots* of downvotes.    So those are some things to watch out for.   This does mean that some otherwise worthwhile questions may get less attention than they deserve, but, well, it's an imperfect world ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: (The biggest thing is demonstrated effort, I think.  People look for evidence that you're not a help vampire; that whatever the problem is, you tried to solve it on your own before asking for other people's time. A code sample, even one that's not strictly necessary to understand the question, can go a long way towards that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, yes, you could watch the window resize and scale your page content to some ratio based on the absolute size you designed it to.

```js
// jQuery used for convenience, but this could be done in vanilla as well
var scalehack = function() {
  var abswidth = 500; // width of the absolutely-positioned layout
  var scale = window.innerWidth / abswidth; // amount to transform to fit the window
  $('#container').css("transform", "scale(" + scale + ")");
};

$(window).on("resize", scalehack);
scalehack();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#container {
  transform-origin: 0 0
}

div.box {
  border:1px solid;
  width: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
  This is text.
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  This is more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

In practice, as you can see by popping the above sample into fullscreen and then resizing the window, this gives very unsatisfactory results: everything scales including the font sizes and images, which will make things unreadably small on mobile screens and unreadably large on larger screens.

I know you're trying to find a way to avoid having to redo all your CSS in the relative units you should have used in the first place, but: honestly you should redo all your CSS in the relative units you should have used in the first place.

Comment: The example you provided is exactly what I was looking for. The scaling font size is just what is supposed to happen. Even if it seems too small for mobile screens. For my purpose it's perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either need to change the initial definitions of the sizes, (i.e. with the style by using percentages), or could use a few js functions referring to the window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth properties. I would use a structure like this if it's not too burdonsome (and you can use Jquery):

```
<style>

#percentage_div{
        width:50%;
        height:50%;
        background-color:red;
}
</style>
<div id="surrounding_div">
    <div id="percentage_div"></div>
</div>

<script>

$("#surrounding_div").css("height",window.innerHeight);
$("#surrounding_div").css("width",window.innerWidth);


$(window).on('resize', function(){ // if the user resizes
    $("#surrounding_div").css("height",window.innerHeight);
    $("#surrounding_div").css("width",window.innerWidth);

});
</script>
```